# React Navigation/TypeScript: Defining initialProps on parent of a nested navigation

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

I cannot seem to define nested routes in the deep linking config AND set initialParams on the parent screen.

In the following example, TypeScript throws an error on the `initialParams` property of the Home screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer, LinkingOptions, NavigatorScreenParams } from '@react-navigation/native';

/**
 * Stack hierarchy:
 *  - Home
 *      - Main (default)
 *      - Add
 *  Profile
 */
type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: NavigatorScreenParams<HomeStackParamList>;
    Profile: { userId: string };
};

type HomeStackParamList = {
    Main: { feed: string };
    Add: { name: string };
};

const DeepLinking: LinkingOptions<RootStackParamList> = {
    prefixes: ['app://'],
    config: {
        screens: {
            Home: {
                screens: {
                    Main: '/',
                    Add: '/add',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

export function App() {
    const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
    return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={DeepLinking}>
            <RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeComponent} initialParams={{ feed: 'latest' }} />
                <RootStack.Screen name="Profile" component={NoopComponent} initialParams={{ userId: '1' }} />
            </RootStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

function HomeComponent() {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator<HomeStackParamList>();
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main">
            <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={HomeComponent} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={NoopComponent} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

function NoopComponent() {
    return <></>;
}
```

How can I include params for the parent route of a nested route?